# How to remove a path in git

Tags: git

Also the question I have a git history that looks like this

```
    F - G - H
  /           \
A - B - C - D - E
```

and now for the sake of clarity I would just like to get rid of the F-G-H path completely.

How can I achieve this ?

---

Post-Edit 1 - trying to make myself clearer, I do not need to preserve *anything* on the path, so what I would like to have eventually is just

```
A - B - C - D - E
```

Post-Edit 2 - Also I make no assumption on the right hand side of E, where there might be further changes from `E` onwards, that do not want to alter.

I am not very familiar with `rebase`, could it do that ?

Comment: Just remove the branch those commits are on

Comment: @TimCastelijns This does not alter the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the changes comming from F, G and H, but don't want to have an actual merge in the history, then you want a squash merge, which is not an actual merge, but creates a new commit with all the changes from the merged in branch squashed.

You'd need to first undo the actual merge (E):

```
git reset --keep HEAD^ #assuming you're on E
```

Then you can just do:

```
git merge --squash H
git commit
```

And your history would look like this:

```
    F - G - H
  /           
A - B - C - D - E
```

But E does have changes from F, G and H. After this, you can remove the branch pointing to H, and it looks like the branch was never there, but the changes are still in the history.

Answer (score 0):

The F G and H commits contains changes that are NOT in the E commit. The E commit is an empty commit (except when there are conflict), being only here to serve as a merge commit, which has two parents.

You can linearize your history using [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) commands, but you F G and H commits will still again around.

Comment: Well, if you're rebasing anyway you can squash them together into E, you don't need to keep F, G, H.

Comment: So yes I guess what I am trying to do looks a little bit like rebasing from A to E on the upper path and squash this into a single changeset, is that what you suggest ?